# Can't find microsoft SDK sample

Tags: c++, sdk, windows-shell

Can't find sources of specific microsoft sdk sample - RegView, it demonstrates namespace extension developing.

Does anybody has it?

Or, there is also nice sample called Window View, from "Visual C++ Shell Programming". Maybe someone can share this one?

Answer (score 0):

I've got an answer on msdn forum,
here is ftp link with RegView sources:

http://cdserv.wbut.ac.in/81-203-2165-0/msdn_vcb/samples/vc98/sdk/winui/shell/regview/